# c# asp.net dropdown list select value

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am getting confused with my code and not sure how to implement what I want.
I have two sql tables one that has OfficeID and matching OfficeName and another one that contains user. I have a page that allows a person to edit information about the person. When the page is loaded it supposed to select from the drop down list the current OfficeName of a person whose information is being edited. Thus I have this:

This is probably extremely inefficient and confusing for my level of knowledge of C# and SQL, but none the less I am determined to learn how to do it. What I have currently is Before the creation of the drop down list I get the users Id, then select from the database his corresponding officeID, then while creating the drop down list I check for the OfficeID to correspond to the ones from the other table. If it found the match it will set it as the selected value for the drop down list.

am I on the right track? I need to figure out how to compare SESLoginID = loginID before I convert loginID before hand. Any help?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Functions;
using HelloApp;

public partial class UserUpdate : Page
{
    private Int32 loginID = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SESLoginID"]);

       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindBusinessUnitDDL();
        }

    }

    protected void BindBusinessUnitDDL()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        string sql;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        int error;
        conn = Database.DBConnect(out error);

        sql = String.Format("SELECT OfficeID FROM SESLogin WHERE SESLoginID = loginID");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader rdrr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ListItem office = new ListItem();
        office.Value = Convert.ToString(rdrr.GetInt32(0));
        Database.DBClose(conn);   

        sql = String.Format(
            "SELECT OfficeID, OfficeName FROM Office");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList ddlBusinessUnit = (DropDownList)(this.LoginFormView.FindControl("ddlBusinessUnit"));

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            ListItem myItem = new ListItem();
            myItem.Value = Convert.ToString(rdr.GetInt32(0));
            myItem.Text = rdr.GetString(1);
            ddlBusinessUnit.Items.Add(myItem);
            if(office.Value == myItem.Value){
                ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue = myItem.Text;
            }
        }
        Database.DBClose(conn);        

        ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();
        PageUser myUser = new PageUser();
    }
```

A different version of the code where there exists a procedure to return OfficeName using an LoginID. Doesnt work either gives an error: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' SELECT
        [OfficeName]
       FROM sesuser.SESLogin
       INNER JOIN sesuser.Office
       ON sesuser.Office.OfficeID = sesuser.SESLogin.OfficeID
       WHERE SESLoginID LIKE '287'' to data type int.

```
public partial class UserUpdate : Page
{
    private Int32 loginID = 0;
    private String loginIDE = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginIDE = Request.QueryString["SESLoginID"];
        loginID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SESLoginID"]);

       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindBusinessUnitDDL();
        }

    }

    protected void BindBusinessUnitDDL()
        {
            SqlConnection connec = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            string sqls = "";
            int errNum = 0;
            connec = Database.DBConnect(out errNum);
            if (errNum != 0)
                throw new Exception("Database Connection Error.");

            sqls = "Login_GetOffice";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqls, connec);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", loginIDE);
            string office = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        SqlConnection conn;
        string sql;
        int error;
        conn = Database.DBConnect(out error);

        sql = String.Format(
            "SELECT OfficeID, OfficeName FROM Office");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList ddlBusinessUnit = (DropDownList)(this.LoginFormView.FindControl("ddlBusinessUnit"));

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            ListItem myItem = new ListItem();
            myItem.Value = Convert.ToString(rdr.GetInt32(0));
            myItem.Text = rdr.GetString(1);
            ddlBusinessUnit.Items.Add(myItem);
            if(office == myItem.Text){
                myItem.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        Database.DBClose(conn);        

        ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();
        PageUser myUser = new PageUser();
    }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `myItem.Selected=true` ?

Comment: changed it, but I assumed my code was doing the same thing :) Cant test it because I am not sure how to find SELECT OfficeID FROM SESLogin WHERE SESLoginID = loginID

Comment: Well not really `SelectedValue` is different from text unless you are binding the same thing to both text and value

Comment: just a pet peeve of mine.  Make your loginId global variable either in a property (where you can do better checking with try parse) or keep it in scope and pass it as a parameter.  I prefer the property approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a DataSource and Bind the results you get from the query say via a DataTable.

Set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

Then you can say something like `ddl.Items.FindByText("requiredloginid").Selected = true` after the Data is bound to the dropdown.

Comment: I updated my question, where I wrote a procedure to return OfficeName for a userID, doesnt seem to work. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Could you check please?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
ddlBusinessUnit.DataBind();?
```

You are binding any data source to the dropdownlist.

Can you specify on which line you are getting error?

Thanks
Ashwani